# Translate Oracle SQL*Plus WHENEVER {X}ERROR to T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, sqlplus

I am given a task to transition Oracle SQL*Plus code to T-SQL.

I have the command `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE` and similarly with OSERROR. I see there is no equivalent for SQL Server. What's the best way to translate it?

I could use a giant TRY CATCH block encapsulating the entire script but doesn't seem optimal.

````
BEGIN TRY
The entire script
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   raiserror(CONCAT("Error: ",@@ERROR))
END CATCH```
````

Comment: I don't want to discover what they do. I know it. I want to understand how to translate them to T-SQL. And unfortunately a translation book does not exist.

Comment: There is a loose equivalent in `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, which aims to abort the whole batch when a failure is encountered. However, without try-catch this still fails to stop on some errors, because T-SQL's error handling is a [hot mess](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html). If you have multiple batches (i.e. you're using `GO`), the common pattern is to do `SET NOEXEC ON` in your error handler, to prevent the rest of the script from executing. This can still raise spurious parse/compilation errors on objects that now don't get created. Again -- hot mess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So essentially you think the best way to catch most errors is to use the try...catch?  Btw trying it out I saw that my error gets raised if I do things like "SELECT 1/0" but it doesn't if I do "SELECT non_existing_column FROM db". Any clue why? (In any case if you put your comment in an answer I'll mark it accepted)

Comment: `SELECT non_existing_column FROM db` results in a compilation error, meaning the engine never even gets to executing the `TRY .. CATCH`. You can't handle errors like that, unless you go to dynamically executing the whole batch with `EXEC`. There is, unfortunately, no single *best* way to handle errors in *every* scenario because it greatly depends on what you're doing, and my recommendation is to read Erland Sommarskog's series of write-ups on it, which I've linked earlier (and is too extensive to summarize in one simple answer).

Comment: Yes I'm reading it. Thanks for pointing at it!